# Fast access of Large Image Dataset

Tags: python, image, large-data

I have multiple large image data set that contains north of 500 images that are 1080p or 4K. I need to process two consecutive images at a time (so pair wise) and the processing needs to be done on individual pixels.

I have tried using python (PIL) but loading the image into memory and then accessing the pixel values takes a lot of time.

What is the fastest way to load these images into memory and run some algorithm's on them?

PS: A solution in any language would do.

Thanks

Comment: One way to speed this up would be to store the image data in a raw format to make loading the pixel data into memory faster, or you could even memory-map the file directly. Do you have to examine every single pixel in every image, or just some subset?

Comment: Unfortunately, every single pixel. Yes, I could try that but the sheer volume and size is scary. I need to carry out some statistical analysis on the pixel values.

Comment: Bit depth? How large are the files/images?

Comment: You might be able to get somewhere with GPU processing depending on the nature of your task, e.g. using something like https://developer.nvidia.com/pycuda

Comment: the images are converted from RGB to Ycbcr. Each image is uncompressed tiff format. The issue is loading it into Memory and then compute multiple times. The IO is the major bottleneck, but other than that, any way I can optimize will be helpful.

Comment: You could try OpenCV - http://opencv.org/ - there are Python bindings for OpenCV.  As stated if you can get the raw/uncompressed data, then Numpy and Scipy might be worthwhile - http://www.scipy-lectures.org/advanced/image_processing/

Comment: I have tried OpenCV but the processing part is already very optimized using parallel processing etc. Its accessing the image that is the issue.

Comment: There may be better StackExchange *forums* to post this question - maybe over at Signal Processing, http://dsp.stackexchange.com/,

Comment: Well thanks a lot for sparing your time, I will surely post there too. Meanwhile, hope someone will come up with a solution.

Comment: libtiff (the thing Pillow will use to load the file) is pretty quick, it should have no trouble saturating your disk channel, and you can't go faster than that. For example, on this machine, I can load a 10,000 x 10,000 pixel RGB TIFF into a numpy array in 0.8s with Pillow. I think your question is too vague. I would write a tiny benchmark program representative of the kind of processing I wanted, profile it, find where time is being spent, and then ask about ways to improve the slower parts.

Comment: Thanks, I will try this and probably post the results